# Marklogic - Interrupting a long running query with a database restart

Tags: restart, marklogic

In Marklogic, if I interrupt a long running query with a database restart, will that query then no-longer be fully applied when the database comes online again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in general canceling an update query will roll back any changes it tried to make. You can think of this like a stack: every update in your query goes into a stack, taking any necessary locks as it goes. After all the expressions have been evaluated, the update enters *commit phase* and applies that stack atomically to the database. If the query is interrupted before that atomic commit, none of the changes are durable. This behavior covers the A=atomic and D=durable aspects of the [ACID properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) common to transactional DBMS implementations.

There are some exceptions. It is possible to structure an update so that work is applied in granular sub-transactions. One way to do that is with a multi-statement transaction.

See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions for more.